# How can I use a JSP to create a dynamic Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I'm using a Jboss5/Spring/Struts implementation, and I'm not familiar enough with JSP technology to know how to do this. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the correct content-type

```
<%@ page contentType="text/javascript" %>
```

… but other than that, JavaScript (like HTML) is just text.